# How to display a word document in a silverlight web page?

Tags: silverlight

I would like to display word docs in our silverlight web application, How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

See also this question: [Displaying Office documents in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697847/displaying-office-documents-in-silverlight). The short answer is that there are several different ways to do it, but they all start by converting the Word document to an XPS format, and then using First Floor's Document Toolkit to display the XPS format in Silverlight.